# Fix or explain tty issue and gpg2

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, gpg, tty

I'm having an issue importing or generating gpg secret keys on ubuntu 18.04 with my main (sudo) non-root user. With root user I have no problems with gpg, but non-root and it's basically permission denied.
When I execute tty, you can see g&o have no read permissions. Is there somewhere I can address this to open it up at boot, and safely?

```
ls -la $(tty);
crw--w---- 1 root tty 136, 1 Sep 13 02:22 /dev/pts/1
```

Comment: How did that become owned by root? Did you login as root? Do you have a script that changed it?

Comment: That was the issue

Comment: Huh? What was the issue?

Comment: I was ssh in via root, then su into my user.